Connection of conformal surface parametrization and surface normal vector field
I need a help with understanding something that is (maybe) obvious, but I'm somehow missing it.
I have a conformal parametrization $x:U\to \mathbb{R}^3$ meaning $E=G=\lambda, F=0$ where $E,F,G$ are coefficients of the first fundamental form, that is
$E=x_u\cdot x_u, F=x_u\cdot x_v, G=x_v\cdot x_v.$ The surface normal field is given by $N=x_u \times x_v/\|x_u \times x_v\|.$
Why for vector fields $x_u, x_v, N$ holds $x_v=N\times x_u$? Does a conformal parametrization imply that?

Because $F=0$, $x_u\cdot x_v=0$, so $x_v$ is a scalar multiple of $N\times x_u$ (as it is orthogonal to both $N$ and $x_u$). In fact, it is a positive scalar multiple, since $x_u,x_v,N$ form a right-handed system. But $\|x_v\|=\|x_u\|=\|N\times x_u\|$ (the latter because $N$ is a unit vector orthogonal to $x_u$), so in fact $x_v=N\times x_u$.

Thank You for the explanation, everything clear now.

You're welcome. When you have no further questions, please accept the answer so that the question will go off the list of unanswered questions. :)
